# onclick react, I want my button to change color

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is more than one button using the map function and display it. Want to change the Background color of a button that I click. And others want it as it is. And again when I click on another button then only change the BG color of that button only.
This is what I have already:

```
const handleClick = (option, index) => {
  const nextQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;
  if (data[currentQuestion].answer === option) {
     // setChangeColor(isCorrect);
     isCorrect = "bg-success text-white";
     setTimeout(() => {
        setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion);
        setMoneyLadder(moneyLadder - 1);
        setChangeColor("");
     }, 2000);
  } else {
     // setChangeColor(isIncorrect);
     isIncorrect = "bg-danger";
     setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.reload();
        setCurrentQuestion(0);
        setMoneyLadder(15);
        setChangeColor("");
     }, 2000);
  }
};


 <div className="answers">
  {data[currentQuestion].options.map(
      (option, index) => (
        <button
            className={
              // data[currentQuestion].answer ===
              // option
              //    ? "text-success"
              //    : ""
            }
            key={index}
            onClick={() =>
              handleClick(option, index)
            }
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `${index + 1})  ${option}`,
            }}
        ></button>
      )
  )}
 </div>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could initialize a state variable with an array of bool (`buttonSelected`). Then, on `handleClick` with `index` you intercept the button clicked and toggle the boolean. In `button`'s style you could write:

```
{{backgroundColor: buttonSelected[index] ? 'red':'green'}}
```

So the backgroundColor becomes `red` if button is clicked, `green` otherwise:

```
const [buttonSelected, setButtonSelected] = useState(new Array(data[currentQuestion].options.length).fill(false));

const handleClick = (index) => {
   let result = [...buttonSelected];
   result[index] = !result[index];
   setButtonSelected(result);
}

<div className="answers">
                          {data[currentQuestion].options.map(
                             (option, index) => (
                                <button
                                   className={
                                      // data[currentQuestion].answer ===
                                      // option
                                      //    ? "text-success"
                                      //    : ""
                                   }
                                   style={{backgroundColor: buttonSelected[index] ? 'red':'green'}}
                                   key={index}
                                   onClick={() =>
                                      handleClick(index)
                                   }
                                   dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                                      __html: `${index + 1})  ${option}`,
                                   }}
                                ></button>
                             )
                          )}
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
But your suggestion is throwing an error "Can't read property 0 of undefined".

Comment: @DeSaint will be most probably related to `new Array(data[currentQuestion].options.length` in `useState`. Check where do you fill `data` and then intialize `buttonSelected` (maybe in some `useEffect` you use to fetch data...).